# Single loop containing multiple if-statements or multiple if-statements with loops inside?

Tags: loops, if-statement

Is it recommended to create multiple if statements and nest loops inside of them or create one loop and nest multiple if statements inside of that? I am wondering in terms of memory, time, and other factors I may have overlooked.

Here is some pseudocode:

`if a:
    for i in range(500):
        do x
if b:
    for i in range(500):
        do y`

versus

`for i in range(500):
    if y:
        do x
    if z:
        do p`

In other words, when is the best time to do the if-statement. Inside a few nested loops or before any of the loops?

I am also wondering this because it may be more efficient to do one if statement at the beginning for a check then do the loops nested in this if statement. However, this might result in lots of repeated code.

Answer (score 1):

The first way is the best for the performances, you do the test one time rather than at each turn

Of course I suppose there is no side effect making the two solutions different

Answer (score 0):

In some situations, you won't be able to check the condition before the loop, but if you can this is the better solution because a condition is checked one time instead of every loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what you are iterating through and what you need to check for!

If you need to check each iteration in both cases `a` and `b` you should go with option 2.

But if it's either `a` or `b` just go with option 1.